# How to use UNION and order by a specific select?

Tags: union, postgresql-9.4

I have two selects:

```
SELECT id FROM a -- returns 1,4,2,3
UNION
SELECT id FROM b -- returns 2,1
```

I'm receiving correct num of rows, like: 1,4,2,3

But I want b table results first: 2,1,4,3 or 2,1,4,3

Comment: Why not simply swap the union operands? E. g. _first_ select from b, _then_ union with _a_?

Comment: @UweKeim: that would still not guarantee any order

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : you right.